# Getting oldValue and newValue of field for char, integer and date fields

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm trying to just keep a history of changes to a table. So I want to get the value of a field before it has been changed to oldValue, then get the value it changed to to newValue. Both values should be cast as strings. So here would be an example of the table:

```
| PartNumber | Description      |
|      12345 | Test Part 1      |
```

And it was changed to:

```
| PartNumber | Description      |
|      12345 | Test Part 2      |
```

I would be able to construct something like: [Description] changed from "Test Part 1" to "Test Part 2"

The DB is an SQLite DB if that helps any. I'm using TFDQuery and TDataSource.

Comment: Maybe it is simpler to keep different versions in different rows? So if some value changes you add new row of that object to the database? So you can track changes easily.

Comment: That would probably be a little overkill for my purposes. This is basically just so that people can look back and see what fields changed, and when. Along with who changed them, but that's already taken care of.

Comment: One way might be writing handler for the `OnUpdateRecord` event and comparing there values of all field's `OldValue` with `NewValue`. But it doesn't look comfortable for FireDAC and I believe that there's a more straightforward way for this.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that but it seems like the overhead would be a bit much. There are actually 61 fields that I need to watch for changes on.

Comment: I think a loop over all dataset fields would do this job still quite quickly, but I feel there should be something ready made. Possibly around cached log updates. Are you using cached updates, btw. ?

Comment: `TField` has an `OnChange` event. Have you considered creating one event handler to store the change in your historic table and assign it to all fields ?

Comment: @Guillem, what if you were using cached updates and change value `A` to `B`, back to `A` and then apply updates ? Your audit log would contain records, but no change would actually happen on the backend.

Comment: @TLama, in that case I would use a `memory dataset` to store the changes. If it would be reverted then I'd empty it. Otherwise, when the cached updates would be applied I'd store them in the real table.

Comment: @Guillem, it's also not much comfortable. Ad cached updates, there is the `TADQuery.Table.Updates` collection which collects the changes. That is the way I would probably follow.

Comment: @Tlama, never used cached updates so you're surely right. Anyway, OP did not say if he uses it. :-)

Comment: I like the OnChange event for TField, but my understanding is that the event fires after the field has been changed. So, how would I find the original value before the change?

Comment: @user2021539, in the `OldValue` property (it remains there until you post the changes to the backend).

Comment: I would simply add a trigger on the table and write changes to a history table...

Comment: @whosrdaddy, that is probably the simplest solution, but it would require to either write the whole record or check every field (and there are a lot as per OP's comment).

Comment: Read the TField OldValue and NewValue property.

Comment: I've done this using BeforePost. Iterate TFields, compare OldValue <> NewValue, and send both values and the fieldname to a logging procedure.