# Get current field in TQuery to a TField

Tags: delphi

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362530/getting-oldvalue-and-newvalue-of-field-for-char-integer-and-date-fields) but doesn't really fit enough to include it with the original. When a Post is called, how can I get the field (or fields) that was modified to a TField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logging, I use the `OnBeforePost` event, which is called (as it says) just before the data is posted. The drawback to this, of course, is that your log table has to have fields wide enough to hold all possible content.

```
procedure TMyData.SomeTableBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    // Skip calculated and lookup fields
    if DataSet.Fields[i].FieldType = ftData then
    begin
      if DataSet.Fields[i].OldValue <> DataSet.Fields[i].NewValue then
      begin
        LogTable.Insert;
        LogTableColumnName.AsString := DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName;
        LogTableOldValue.Value := DataSet.Fields[i].OldValue;
        LogTableNewValue.Value := DataSet.Fields[i].NewValue;
        LogTable.Post;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OldValue and NewValue are only available if the dataset is using CachedUpdates.

Comment: @crefird: That's not true. It's available in a plain old TDataSet; I use those values all the time in apps that have nothing to do with TClientDataset or cached updates. (Where do you think the values come from if you abort in `OnBeforePost`?)

Comment: @KenWhite try it with a TTable and you will get a "Table1: Not in cached update mode" exception unless you have set CachedUpdates to true.

Comment: @KenWhite I only used TTable to look a solution for this question.  I normally use FireDAC.  Yes I know the BDE is antiquated, but I find it interesting that demos for commercial components often use BDE.

Comment: @crefird: I don't use any current commercial components that use the BDE for demos, so I can't speak for them. I use ADO and a third-party component set for some legacy data, neither of which have any linkage to the BDE.